# Bootstrap affix with jquery computed height *Edited with Snippet*

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have a bootstrap navbar at the bottom of the page when it load's and stick to the top when I scroll pass the navbar.

I have tried affix

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp

It is working great but....

we need to specify the height to be scrolled to. In my case I need it to be at the bottom of any size screen. So the 100% sized element is working but I still need to tel affix the ammount of pixel I will scroll to.

The Snippet will work fine. the code seams to be working fine but i'm giving a value to a html data attribute and it kinda stick with it. Even if I change the value using jquery. I can notice it when the screen get smaller and the navbar stick to the top to late or to many pixels after the navbar.

Try to run the snippet in full screen and resize your browser window to half of your screen.

Can anyone help me work arround this. Any working exemple of similiar navbar behavior? willing to code some more!

```js
  var wtf;
$(document).ready(function(){

       var $nav = $('#nav');
       var $mainImg = $('#mainImg');
       var $window = $(window).on('resize', function(){
       var height = $(this).height() - $nav.height();
       $mainImg.height(height);
       $nav.attr("data-offset-top",height);
       wtf=height
     
    }).trigger('resize'); //on page load
 
});

$(document).ready (function(){
  var atr = $("#nav").data('offset-top');
   $("#nav").attr("data-offset-top", wtf);

});
```

```css
.navbar {
   
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
  
}
.mainImg{
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
    background-image:url('../images/mainImg.png');
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
}
 .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body id="body">
<div id="mainImg" class="container-fluid mainImg">

</div>



<nav id="nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="899">
   <div class="container"> 

<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">ROUTESRATE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ROUTE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
  <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```